# Nested list remove duplicate list

Tags: list, python-2.7

In a nested list (like the one below) that is continuous,
I want to remove duplicate entry where first and third are equal values. What is the most efficient way of doing this?

```
 [[a, 1, a], [b, 1, b], [c, 2, d],[e, 4,g]
```

Return

```
 [[c, 2, d],[e, 4,g]]
```

Comment: Said more clearly you want to return all sublists which are *not* like `[x, y, x]`. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> seq = [['a', 1, 'a'], ['b', 1, 'b'], ['c', 2, 'd'],['e', 4, 'g']]
>>> seq = [item for item in seq if item[0] != item[2]]
>>> print seq
[['c', 2, 'd'], ['e', 4, 'g']]
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is go through each sublist, and go through each item in that sublist. I there is a duplicate item in that sublist set the flag to True and ignore it, if not then append that list to a new list.

```
lists = [['a', 1, 'a'], ['b', 1, 'b'], ['c', 2, 'd'],['e', 4,'g']]
newLists = []
for l in lists:
    if l[0] != l[len(l) - 1]:
        newLists.append(l)

print newLists
```

Comment: This looks like it would incorrectly eliminate some values. For example, `['e', 'e','g']` would be removed even though its first item doesn't equal its third item.